# Best way to handle multiple conditions

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

I try to make a variable in which I can add multiple conditions to use it in a while-statement

```
conditionData = "False"

def conditionConstructor(xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd, conditionData):
    conditionData += " or (({} < x < {}) and ({} < y < {}))".format(xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd)
    return conditionData

conditionConstructor(1, 2, 3, 4, conditionData)
conditionConstructor(3, 4, 1, 2, conditionData)

while(conditionData):
...
```

What's the best way to do that? Maybe there is a way without using a string?

Comment: Did you mean: `while (xStart < x < xEnd) and (yStart < y < yEnd):`?

Comment: I juste edited my question, I hope it's clearer

Comment: you realize your `while` is evaluating the truth-iness of a string variable (always True when other than `""` empty string), not an actual condition.  Put in a known-False data and you'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a series of `lambda`s to get what you want.

Strings were never the way.

```py
def conditionConstructor(xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd, condition = lambda x,y:False):
    return lambda x,y: condition(x,y) or (xStart < x < xEnd) and (yStart < y < yEnd)


c1 = conditionConstructor(1, 2, 3, 4)
c2 = conditionConstructor(3, 4, 1, 2, c1)

x = 1.1
y = 3.3
while c2(x,y):
    print(x,y)
    x += 0.3
    y += 0.3
```

output:

```
1.1 3.3
1.4000000000000001 3.5999999999999996
1.7000000000000002 3.8999999999999995
```

Answer (score 0):

To use strings as code, you need to use `eval` function, carefully, as it isn't a safe function if you rely on input from a user.
Note that f-strings are an improved `format`.

```
def conditionConstructor(xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd, conditionData='False'):
    return f'{conditionData} or (({xStart} < x < {xEnd}) and ({yStart} < y < {yEnd}))'


def main():
    x = 2
    y = 4
    res = conditionConstructor(1, 3, 3, 5)
    res = conditionConstructor(3, 4, 1, 2, res)

    while eval(res):
        ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Printing the first `res` will show:
`False or ((1 < x < 3) and (3 < y < 5))`.

Printing the second res will show:
`False or ((1 < x < 3) and (3 < y < 5)) or ((3 < x < 4) and (1 < y < 2))`